# What is the purpose of the SCR in this circuit?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, scr

[image]

I am trying to repair an old SMPS. The first step is to reconstruct the schematic and work from there on. The schematic on the low voltage side is completed for the +12V and the +5V circuits. However what is the functionality of the SCR and Zener in the circuit.

1. Since VR4 is a zener I have been thinking of the +5 going up over the 
   threshold of 6.2V but that would not trigger the SCR.
2. If the +5V is going down the zener would act as a diode and the SCR would 
   trigger if the +5V line comes below GND. But in that case the zener functions 
   as a diode.

Comment: comment rather than answer. The gate's connected to ground, normally VR4 (unusual ref des for a zener?) will be rev biassed by the 5v. If 5v goes -ve wrt gnd by more than 2 or 3 volts, the SCR will be triggered, either collapsing +12v, or recruiting the +12v to get the +5v back up again? Is VR4 beefy enough to do that? Interesting puzzle.

Comment: @Neil_UK  VR4 = 1N5234 (500mW)

Comment: I think your schematic reconstruction is [fawlty](https://resources.stuff.co.nz/content/dam/images/1/e/w/h/f/3/image.related.StuffLandscapeSixteenByNine.620x349.1ewfrv.png/1476822972248.jpg)

Comment: @Andyaka  You are right. I verified the symbol in the drawing database with the original datasheet and I found that the Gate and the Cathode are interchanged.

Comment: Then it's starting to look like a crowbar circuit but you should update the diagram to be sure.

Comment: @Andyaka  It is clear now. It is a crowbar circuit. At the moment the +5V increases to much (error condition) then the +12V is shorted. Is it interesting to show the solution with my own answer?